# How to change the Ajax combo box list items width dynamically from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a Ajax combo box whose width is set from a css class, i want to change the width of list items (the area which appears after we click the button on combo box present at right side). from the code behind.
I've set the width of listitems from css like

```
         .ComboboxWidth ul
          {
              width:176px !important;
          }
```

This works. But i've to do same thing from code behind, can anybody guide?

Comment: Why do you want to do this server side when it can be done on the client saving server load?

Comment: The combo box width is dynamic and it changes in certain situation. To change the width there are some calculation at code behind. Whenever the text area of combo box increases i also need to increase the width of list area.